# libgdx point light not working on generated mesh

Tags: android, opengl-es, 3d, libgdx

I've been trying to illuminate plane meshes generated by the following:

```
private Model createPlane(float w, float h, Texture texture) {
   Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 4, 6, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, "a_position"),
           new VertexAttribute(Usage.TextureCoordinates, 2, "a_texCoord0"),
           new VertexAttribute(Usage.Normal, 3, "a_normal")); 

   float w2 = w * this.CELL_SIZE;
   float h2 = h * this.CELL_SIZE;

    mesh.setVertices(new float[]
            { w2, 0f, h2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            w2, 0f, -h2, 0, h, 0, 1, 0,
            -w2, 0f, h2, w, 0, 0, 1, 0,
            -w2, 0f, -h2 , w,h, 0, 1, 0
            });
    mesh.setIndices(new short[] { 0, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2});
    Model model = ModelBuilder.createFromMesh(mesh, GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, new Material(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(texture)));
    return model;
}
```

and are rendered using:

```
//the environment setup
env = new Environment();
        env.set(new ColorAttribute(ColorAttribute.AmbientLight, 0.4f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1f));
        env.add(new PointLight().set(Color.ORANGE, 5f, 1f, 5f, 10f));
        env.add(new DirectionalLight().set(Color.WHITE, -1f, -0.8f, -0.2f));
...
//the render method
batch.begin();
batch.render(inst, env);//inst is a ModelInstance created using the Model generated from createPlane(...)
batch.end();
```

The meshes display correctly (UVs, textured) and seem to be properly affected by directional and ambient lighting.

When I try to add a point light (see above environment) none of the planes generated from createPlane(...) are affected. I've tried creating another bit of geometry using the ModelBuilder class's createBox(...) and it seems to properly respond to the point light. Because of that I'm assuming that I'm not generating the plane correctly, but the fact that it's apparently being affected by directional/ambient light is throwing me off a bit.

It's worth noting that the size of the planes generated vary, I'm not particularly sure if a point light would affect 4 vertices very much but I expected more than nothing. Moving the point light around (closer to certain vertices) doesn't do anything either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I would try putting your light directly on one corner of the mesh and enlarging its strength by a huge amount to see if one of those is your issue. A four-vertex mesh is not going to respond well to point lights that don't have a reach greater than about twice the distance between vertices, unless you use a shader with per-pixel ilghting.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great to know which shader you are using. The default one? I am not sure if they fixed that already, they had a bug a while ago, where pointlightning was only working on some devices (this had something todo with the implementation of opengles by the manufacturer. I personally fixed this by using my own shader.

Edit: [This seems to be fixed](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1493)

I checked the code I am using. The problem was to determine the correct light array in the shader.
Did it like this in the end:

```
    // on some devices this was working
    int u_lightPosition = program.getUniformLocation("u_lightPosition[0]");
    int u_lightColors = program.getUniformLocation("u_lightColor[0]");
    if(u_lightPosition < 0 && u_lightColors < 0) {
        // on others this was working
        u_lightPosition = program.getUniformLocation("u_lightPosition");
        u_lightColors = program.getUniformLocation("u_lightColor");
    }
```

I hope this helps!